# use 1 css class to swap style for children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to toggle a single class .active  on a div id="slot1".

The div has 2 child divs.  When .active is NOT applied to the div, one child1 is yellow, child2 is green. 
When I apply do something like $("#slot").addClass("active"), I want child1 to be blue and child2 to be red.

How do I write the css for the "children" so that toggling .active on their parent "slot" makes them switch states

```
.normal{}
.active{}
.a{color:yellow;}
.b{color:green;}

.a [when .active is applied to my daddy] {color:blue;}
.b [when .active is applied to my daddy] {color:red;}

<div id="slot1" class="normal">
  <div class="a">normal I'm yellow, with active I'm blue</div>
  <div class="b">normal I'm green, with active I'm red</div>
</div>

<div id="slot2" class="normal active">
  <div class="a">normal I'm yellow, with active I'm blue</div>
  <div class="b">normal I'm green, with active I'm red</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.a{color:yellow;}
.b{color:green;}

#slot1.active .a, #slot2.active .a {color:blue;} /*No daddy selector, but you can just get the child of .active*/
#slot1.active .b, #slot2.active .b {color:red;}
```

Comment: ok, so what I was looking for ended up being .normal.active a  but thanks, you put me on track

Answer (score 2):

Normal

```
.normal .a {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Active

```
.normal.active .a {
    background: blue;
}
```

For the other children it's equivalent, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCcSL/2/)

If you want the to select on the direct ancestor only (daddy), you must use the child selector `>`

```
.normal > .a {
    background: yellow;
}

.normal.active > .a {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fiddle.  turns out I was looking for .normal.active a and seeing the fiddle helped me get it right.

Comment: `.normal.active > .a` works even better, since it is more specific and thus not order dependent, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCcSL/3/). I updated the answer accordingly.